# Simple CRM 2011 Collections Syntax

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

In CRM 2011, I wish to create a collection of a specific entity. I've tried using the following without luck. It may be my syntax is just off, or I may be using the wrong type of declaration. I am using the Early Bound technique.

```
DataCollection<SalesOrderDetail> orderDetails = new DataCollection<SalesOrderDetail>();
```

That appears to work with certain types of queries, but not as self-defined. Compilation Error: "The type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.DataCollection' has no constructors defined"

What is the proper way of defining a generic collection for CRM? After this code block, I build individual a handful of SalesOrderDetail entities, then I want to Add them to the collection:

```
orderDetails.AddRange(od1, od2, od3);
```

Should I just be using a generic List? I assumed it better to use the SDK methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to just use generics, e.g.

```
List<Account> Accounts = new List<Account>();
```

Or IEnumerable, IQueryable depending on the context of the situation. To add a range of entities to a generic you can just use:

```
List<Account> Accounts = new List<Account>();
Account a1 = new Account();
Account a2 = new Account();
Account a3 = new Account();
Accounts.AddRange(new List<Account> { a1, a2, a3 });
```

If you did want something more reusable, all the early bound entities are freely converted to and from the Microsoft.Sdk.Entity class e.g.

```
List<Entity> Entities = new List<Entity>();
```

The above collection could store all different kinds of entities in one list.

Comment: Using the generics works fine, I'll go with that since CRM doesn't seem to have its own collections that work in this case.